# New to Java and cant seem to fix error; Class, Interface or Enum expected. 274062

Tags: java, netbeans

I just started my java tutorials and as part of my first exercise, i was asked to:

a) Create a new class for a real-world object (i chose mobile phone): mobile 
b) For this class, create an interface that defines its behavior, then require your class to implement it.

I used Netbeans for this exercise and this is the code i wrote/extended:

```
    package mobile;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

public class Mobile {
    int volume = 0;
    int ringtone = 0;

void volumeUp (int increment){
    volume = volume + increment;
}
void changeringtone (int newValue){
    ringtone = newValue;
}
void volumeDown (int decrement){
    volume = volume - decrement;
}
void printStates(){
    System.out.println("ringtone:" + ringtone + "volume:" + volume);
}
```

}

However when i run it, i get this error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mobile/Mobile (wrong name: mobile/mobile)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Could not find the main class: mobile.Mobile.  Program will exit.

I am kindly requesting if anyone can please, first of all, point out to me the mistakes in my code and secondly, how i can fix these problems inside of Netbeans.

Thank you in advance!

karramelle

Comment: On this site it is considered good behavior to choose an answer that you found most helpful and click the check mark to accept it. We would appreciate it if you did so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you may not even need the main() method unless you are writing code to test your class. As thinksteep suggested, you can move the main() method inside your Mobile class. Alternatively, you can remove it all together in order to compile your code. However, note that you must have a main() method *somewhere* in order to run your program.

Comment: Hi Code-Guru, thanks for the tips! for sure i take it in consideration in the course of learning java. cheers!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please come back if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 4):

main method (any method) should be inside class. Right after package & imports, it should be class. Please spend sometime to read [Java Syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm).

```
    public class Mobile {
    //Variables declarations 
    //Instance blocks etc.,
     public static void main(String[] args) {

//Your code here
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi thinksteep, thank you so much. you are right about Java Syntax, thats what i spent the last 1 1/2 hours reading thru. i got some insights from the site and manage to fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the java language issue (methods reside inside the class bodies), I'd like to encourage you to change the *architecture* of your small application.

You're asked to write an interface first and after that an implementation of that interface. You've chosen a mobile phone, not bad, but then your `Mobile` should be the interface and another class (`IPh**e` or `No**a`) should provide the real implemention of that interface.

And then I'd use a third class for the main method. Name it `User` - that would be the class that calls the method on an instance of an implementation of `Mobile`.

So in brief:

```
public class Me {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mobile myPhone = new Nokia();  // we "buy" a mobile
    myPhone.setVolume(11);         // that's more then 10 ;)
  }
}
```

---

```
public interface Mobile {
  void setVolume(int level);  // as an example
}
```

---

```
public class Nokia implements Mobile {
  // (1) a constructor
  // (2) implementations for all methods defined on Mobile
}
```

Comment: Hi Andreas_D, many thanks for this. i manage to fix my first error and now im trying to really answer the rest of the questions posed in the exercise and yes your response helped alot in terms of creating an interface that defines the object behavior, then enabling the class to implement it. Thanks alot once again!!!